# Remove all values from column 3/4 that aren't present in column 1/2 in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list a list of thousands of gene probes that are significantly expressed when an organism is treated with Nickel, with the fold change. I also have a list of all the probes' expression of a mixture of Nickel and copper as such:

```
Significant Nickel        All Nickel x Copper   
Probe ID    Fold Change   Probe ID  Fold Change
GENE:JGI_V11_3119540303 2.1131195630999 GENE:JGI_V11_3134270303 
7.33122398047945
GENE:JGI_V11_3119540203 2.11312026927122    GENE:JGI_V11_1014720202 
8.21862804193927
GENE:JGI_V11_2024180303 2.1046018264743 GENE:JGI_V11_1159220202 
6.4641324414395
GENE:JGI_V11_1981410203 2.47681459192977    GENE:JGI_V11_954070203  
5.59242208132317
GENE:JGI_V11_3198630203 3.7098848592887 GENE:JGI_V11_287750103  
3.48431361121183
GENE:JGI_V11_3052790202 2.68988523655548    GENE:JGI_V11_3134280203 
22.0832776118516
```

I want to remove all of the probes (and their corresponding fold change) that are not present in the first and second columns in order to create a set of graphs.

How do I do this?

Comment: You could simplify your example, so we see columns A, B, C and D clearly. Then you could drop the technical terms and talk about the concept. Your data sample is hard to read and the jargon makes your question harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper column and count how many times the value in column C appears in column A

```
=countif(A:A,C1)
```

Copy down. The rows with 0 as the result are not in column A. Sort the results and delete the rows with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the lines you want to delete have **empty cells in the 1 et 2 Colomns** ?

If so, I think the easiest way to do this is with **Filters**.

You select the 1st line of your colomns and apply Filters :
Using the "Empty" filter on the 1st Colomn will show instantly all the Empty colomns (with a value in 3rd and 4th Colomns)

But maybe I am mistaking and you have values all along ?